# Failed to install Tomcat6 service in windows server 2003 enterprises

Tags: windows-server-2003, tomcat6

When I try to install Tomcat6 I am getting this error

```
---------------------------
Apache Tomcat Setup
---------------------------
Failed to install Tomcat6 service.

Check your settings and permissions.

Ignore and continue anyway (not recommended)?
---------------------------
Abort   Retry   Ignore   
---------------------------
```

There is no other version installed in the server.

Answer (score 0):

My problem got solved by following the instrucing given in this site below.
may be it will be useful for others if they face the same problem.

http://www.garyrgilbert.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/9/30/64Bit-Windows-Tomcat--Service